# How can I select elements that don't have any of several classes using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, filter

I have a page with many elements that have the same class attached to them:

```
<div class="everyDiv"></div>
<div class="everyDiv"></div>
<div class="everyDiv"></div>
<div class="everyDiv"></div>
...
```

I add additional classes based on filters the user chooses to hide/display them:

```
<div class="everyDiv hide1"></div>
<div class="everyDiv hide2"></div>
<div class="everyDiv hide3"></div>
<div class="everyDiv hide2 hide3"></div>
...
```

Now, I need to select a range (using `slice()`) of the `.everyDiv` elements that **DON'T** have any of the "hide" classse - `.hide1 .hide2 .hide3`.

How can I do this with jQuery?

I've tried the following without success:

```
$("div.everyDiv").not(".hide1").not(".hide2").not(".hide3").slice(n1, n2);

$("div.everyDiv:not(.hide1):not(.hide2):not(.hide3)").slice(n1, n2);
```

This doesn't work either:

```
$("div.everyDiv:not(.hide1), div.everyDiv:not(.hide2), div.everyDiv:not(.hide3)").slice(n1, n2);
```

Basically, all of the "hide#" classes have CSS of `display: none;`, so I need to select my specified range of the divs that aren't "hidden".

Comment: So you **do** want select elements that have a `hide#` class?

Comment: Actually, what you're using is supposed to do as intended. There is a typo in your second selector. Could that be the cause?

Comment: Don't you want elements which don't have all three hide classes?

Comment: @Michael Mior: He means they're picking up elements with any one or two of the hide classes but not all three.

Comment: What event are you using `.click` try `.live` instead.

Comment: What does this have to do with events @dotty?

Comment: @BoltClock "DON'T have any" seems to be equal to "don't have ALL THREE" since any consists of three.

Comment: @Michael Mior: The selector that would exclude only elements with **all three** hide classes would be `div.everyDiv:not(.hide1.hide2.hide3)`. That's very different from the selector that excludes elements that have **any of the three** hide classes, which is the second one he's using.

Comment: @Michael-Mior, that is correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

this should do it:

```
$('div.everyDiv:not(.hide1, .hide2, .hide3)').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s9uyk/

as per comments: making it a little more obvious what the fiddle is doing:
not it adds a class to all the ones that DON'T Have any of the hide classes.
http://jsfiddle.net/s9uyk/2/

Comment: Your code is pretty counterintuitive, maybe you should use something other than `hide()` to demonstrate it. But it does work, I'm not sure what Neal is saying.

Comment: if you say so ;)   changed it to add a class to them instead of hiding.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div.everyDiv').not(".hide1, .hide2, .hide3")
```

with a working [Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SuperPhil/u5QeN/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.everyDiv:not(.hide1), div.everyDiv:not(.hide2), div.everyDiv:not(.hide3)");
```

Comment: This is a very good solution. The chosen solution for this question did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.everyDiv").not(".hide1").not(".hide2").not(".hide3");
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
$("div.everyDiv").not(".hide1, .hide2, .hide3")
```

It is successfully selecting the elements that DON'T have `.hide1`, `.hide2`, `.hide3`. checkout my example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mTkNL/1/) . It is successfully hiding the elements that don't match the criteria, leaving the ones that don't visible. In this case it leaves 1,2,3,4 visable, because they DO have the `.hide1`, `.hide2`, `.hide3` classes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/mTkNL/

Comment: yeah, you're right. it does work there. maybe I have something else wrong with my code. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("[class=class2]")
```

or

```
$('.someclass[class="someclass"]')
```

Comment: This is an OK trick except it looks at the exact class. Depending on the OP's actual code this may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your selector is fine - you're just not doing anything with it.  Try this:

```
$("div.everyDiv").not(".hide1").not(".hide2").not(".hide3").fadeOut(1000);
```

You can also simplify this selector:

```
$("div.everyDiv").not(".hide1, .hide2, .hide3").fadeOut(1000);
```

You can see it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nS4jC/1/